# Python - diff-like order comparision of 2 lists with unequal sizes,

Tags: python, list, dataset

I want to compare two lists and check, if the elements are in the same order:

```
a = [e, f, g, h, i]
b = [e, f, h, i, j, g]
```

I know the following approach, but that works only for lists of the same size:

```
[i for i, j in zip(a, b) if i == j]
```

How can I show diff-like the differences between two lists? As I said,  I'm not talking about intersection (only) since the order matters as well.

I try to archive an output like:

```
a, b
e, e OK
f, f OK
g, h NOK
h, i NOK
i, j NOK
null, g NOK
```

Is there maybe any built-in function, at least for diffing 2 sets in the way described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) for this (note that this is renamed [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) in Python 3.x):

```
 [i for i, j in izip_longest(a, b) if i == j]
```

Once the shorter itertable is exhausted, `izip_longest` will use whatever is entered as the `fillvalue` keyword argument (in this, `None`, since we didn't provide the parameter).

**Edit:**

If you want output that matches what you have in your original question, you can do this:

```
>>> print("\n".join(["{}, {} {}OK".format(i, j, "" if i == j else "N") for i, j in izip_longest(a, b, fillvalue="null")]))
e, e OK
f, f OK
g, h NOK
h, i NOK
i, j NOK
null, g NOK
```

Comment: Drop the `fillvalue`, it would be better with `None` I guess

Comment: Also, this filters all the matched data only :)

Comment: I can't tell if he wants to do that or not...I'll edit to address printing them all out.

Comment: Your answer assumes Python 2.

Comment: @Hammerite Added a note that it's renamed `zip_longest` in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

You could use enumerate and add on the elements from the longer list.

```
a = ["e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
b = ["e", "f", "h", "i", "j", "g"]

m_len = len(min(a, b))
mx = max(a, b)
d = [[a[i], b[i], "Ok"] if a[i] == b[i] else [ a[i], b[i],"NOK"] for i, j in enumerate(min(a, b))]
d += [["null", x, "NOK"] for x in mx[m_len:]]
print "a" ," b"
for i,j,k in d:
    print('{}, {} {}'.format(i, j, k))


a  b
e, e Ok
f, f Ok
g, h NOK
h, i NOK
i, j NOK
null, g NOK
```

Comment: Actually it gives an error, when the list have different sizes:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myhome/listvalidate.py", line 38, in <module>
    diff_list(des_filelist, dir_list)
  File "/home/myhome/listvalidate.py", line 30, in diff_list
    d = [[a[i], b[i], "OK"] if a[i] == b[i] else [a[i], b[i], "NOK"] for i, j in enumerate(min(a, b))]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: you should not get an index error as it enumerates over the shortest list. a and b are different sizes in the example

Comment: Figured it out: one list was UTF-8, the other one ASCII encoded. They had to have the same encoding, now it works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding a second answer for this, because it's a very different approach...

You can use [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) for this, if you want truly diff-like functionality. For example:

```
>>> for x in difflib.unified_diff(a, b, lineterm=""): print(x)
... 
--- 
+++ 
@@ -1,5 +1,6 @@
 e
 f
-g
 h
 i
+j
+g

>>> for x in difflib.ndiff(a, b): print(x)
... 
  e
  f
- g
  h
  i
+ j
+ g
```

I'm not sure if this is really what you want, given the example output you provided, but just letting you know it exists.

Comment: Thank you very much for demonstrating the possibilities of Python functions and methods!